# Optional non-trivial destructor using requires

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, requires-clause

What is the correct way to declare an optional non-trivial destructor using C++ 20 requires? For copy constructor and move constructors it has worked for me to declare the non trivial requires copy/move constructor first and then the default declaration, but for destructors I'm getting weird behaviour:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
concept TriviallyDestructible = std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>;
template<typename T>
concept NotTriviallyDestructible = !TriviallyDestructible<T>;

template<typename T>
struct OptionalDestructor
{
    T value;

    ~OptionalDestructor() requires NotTriviallyDestructible<T>
    {

    }
    ~OptionalDestructor() = default;
};


int main()
{
    static_assert(TriviallyDestructible<OptionalDestructor<int>>);
    static_assert(!TriviallyDestructible<OptionalDestructor<std::string>>);
}
```

is not compiling on clang trunk for me, while

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
concept TriviallyDestructible = std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>;
template<typename T>
concept NotTriviallyDestructible = !TriviallyDestructible<T>;

template<typename T>
struct OptionalDestructor
{
    T value;

    ~OptionalDestructor() = default;
    ~OptionalDestructor() requires NotTriviallyDestructible<T>
    {

    }
};


int main()
{
    static_assert(TriviallyDestructible<OptionalDestructor<int>>);
    static_assert(!TriviallyDestructible<OptionalDestructor<std::string>>);
}
```

is compiling the way I would expect it to. On apple clang I cannot get an optional destructor to compile at all, and MSVC has different behaviour consider orders again...
Which compiler is behaving correctly here?

https://godbolt.org/z/Tvjo9e4nx

GCC seems to compile both orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC is correct. The order should not matter.

[Clang documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx20) indicates that it hasn't yet implemented [P0848](https://wg21.link/P0848), which would make your example compile. It's surprising to me that Clang does compile the example in one order but not the other, and that MSVC behaves similarly, but I guess they just look at the first prospective destructor.